# Subtracting the results of the two SQL subqueries that returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to subtract the results from the two sub queries that I have but I want to return more than 1 row because I want to look at the total calls and their difference for a specific date range and the code below is giving me an error of "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression". Hoping you can help me on this. Please note that this is part of a stored procedure. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT distinct 

c.reporting as 'Agent_ID'
,count(a.pkey) as 'Total_Calls_Handled'
,a.MidnightStartDate as 'Call_Start_Time'
,datename(dw,a.midnightstartdate) as 'Week_day'
,a.[queue]

into #temp3
FROM t1 a
join t2 b
on a.FKAgent = b.fkagent
join t3 c
on a.agent = c.reporting
where a.agent in (

  '132568'
 ,'116308'
,'132083'
,'113737'

)

and convert(date, midnightstartdate) BETWEEN '08/29/16' AND '08/30/19'
group by c.Reporting,a.MidnightStartDate,a.[queue]


SELECT distinct b.[Week_Day], a.[Queue],[Total ACD Calls], [Total ACD Calls Handled], count([total_calls_handled]) as 'Total ACD Calls Handledby Agent', 

(select ((select [total acd calls handled] from #temp2) -
(select count([total_calls_handled]) from #temp3))) as 'OperatorsCalls' 

INTO #Temp4
FROM #Temp2 a
JOIN #Temp3 b
ON a.[Queue] = b.[Queue]
GROUP BY [Total ACD Calls], [Total ACD Calls Handled], b.[Week_Day] , a.[Queue],[total_calls_handled]
```

Comment: your #temp2 table probably contains  MULTIPLE rows of results, and you're using the select on it in a context where only a SINGLE record with a SINGLE value can be returned.

Comment: Yes, it has multiple rows. The code above works if the date range is only for 1 day. But I want to see the difference for the whole week lets say. Is there a way that I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best shot at it without having a working SQL fiddle so apologies if it is not spot on. Essentially you would need to make a temp table before to load the data, do the calculations (which can then maintain a multiple row format), then join it to your final insert into the #temp4 table at the end.

```
SELECT distinct 

c.reporting as 'Agent_ID'
,count(a.pkey) as 'Total_Calls_Handled'
,a.MidnightStartDate as 'Call_Start_Time'
,datename(dw,a.midnightstartdate) as 'Week_day'
,a.[queue]

into #temp3
FROM t1 a
join t2 b
on a.FKAgent = b.fkagent
join t3 c
on a.agent = c.reporting
where a.agent in (

'132568'
,'116308'
,'132083'
,'113737'

)

and convert(date, midnightstartdate) BETWEEN '08/29/16' AND '08/30/19'
group by c.Reporting,a.MidnightStartDate,a.[queue]

--new temp table to load temp3 counts
SELECT
    Count(total_calls_handled) as total_calls_handled_count,
    queue
 INTO #Temp3Counts
FROM
    #temp3
 GROUP BY queue, total_calls_handled

-- new temp table to handled subquery calculations
SELECT 
    T2.Queue,
    (T2.[Total acd calls handled]-T3.total_calls_handled_count) as       'OperatorsCalls'
INTO #temp2Calc
FROM
    #temp2 as T2
INNER JOIN 
#temp3Counts as T3
ON T2.Queue = T3.Queue

GROUP BY T2.Queue,T2.[Total acd calls handled],T3.total_calls_handled_count



SELECT distinct b.[Week_Day], a.[Queue],[Total ACD Calls], [Total ACD Calls      Handled], count([total_calls_handled]) as 'Total ACD Calls Handledby Agent',     T2C.OperatorsCalls

INTO #Temp4
FROM #Temp2 a
JOIN #Temp3 b
ON a.[Queue] = b.[Queue]
INNER JOIN
    #Temp2Calc as T2C
ON T2C.queue = a.queue
GROUP BY b.[Week_Day], a.queue,[Total ACD Calls],[Total ACD Calls Handled],    [total_calls_handled],T2C.OperatorsCalls
```

Comment: If you could mark it as the answer it can help future searches for people potentially :)